# Spring boot, how to specify the order when multiple @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)

Tags: spring-boot, operator-precedence

I have a class that runs after the App starts, it has the annotation:

`@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)`

Which is ok, the problem is that in my project there is a library(dependency) with the same annotation and it runs after mine, I need to specify the order/priority so the code at the dependency is executed before mine..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use @Order(value=x)

Where x = the needed order value